# Removing nonstandard USB plug from socket

Tags: usb, motherboard, usb-2, dongle

An employee wanted to charge their cellphone on their desktop computer and used a PortaPow USB Data Blocker dongle. ([front image](https://portablepowersupplies.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/PureInPalm.jpg); [back image](https://portablepowersupplies.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/PureBehind.jpg)).

The problem we are now facing is that the dongle is stuck in the computer's USB socket. It comes out about half way but appears to be hooking on the computer's socket in the nonstandard empty space of the dongle, [which should normally be bridged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Fbt.jpg). The socket has a small piece of metal, folded inwards (in to the socket) that looks to be stuck on.

Furthermore, the [end half of the dongle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw89u.jpg) looks to be bent upwards, further causing it to catch on that folded metal piece.

Is there any safe way of removing this dongle without damaging the USB socket? We've already trimmed the dongle down to just the PCB and the male plug -- the dongle's shell and socket were cut and removed.

Furthermore, as we were trimming the dongle, I noticed the entire socket stack on the motherboard* lean to the side. We tried to minimise this as best as possible, but is there a way to ensure this socket is not damaged or dangerous (fire risk, etc.)? The victim computer is normally run 24/7.

---

* Socket stack from top to bottom: **PS/2 socket** (unoccupied); **USB 2.0 socket** (unoccupied); **USB 2.0 socket** (stuck dongle).

Comment: I have fixed this before (and my elderly X230 continues to work fine.  See if you can insert a thin screwdriver or strong pin to unhook the clips. Grab the USB plug with good needle nosed pliers and carefully wiggle and pull . The goal is to get the plug out with as little damage to the socket as possible. Manual dexterity and skill required.

Comment: Removing all power, and using thin and narrow tools to slide in and release the caught bits is the way to do this. Patience required.